# The concepts of "left" and "right" in the context of Chi-Square distributions

Tags: statistics, terminology

In Elementary Stat (Picturing the World) by Larson, Section 6.4 is on Confidence Intervals for Variance and Standard Deviation. On page 347, in that section, we see Example 2. The example contains this passage:

[image]

The author found critical values for Chi-Square Right and Chi-Square Left, and then used them to find the two endpoints of the confidence interval. But he used Chi-Square Right to find the left endpoint, and he used Chi-Square Left to find the right endpoint.

I understand that we have two fractions with the same numerator and positive denominators, and the fraction with the bigger denominator will be closer to zero. But why don't we call that bigger denominator Chi-Square L? What makes one of the Chi-Square values "right" or "left" except that it is related to the right or left end of the confidence interval?

Could we talk this way instead?

- (1 - c) / 2 is the area to the **LEFT** of Chi-Square **LEFT**; (n - 1) (s^2) / (X2 **LEFT**) is the **LEFT** end of the confidence interval.
- (1 - c) / 2 is the area to the **RIGHT** of Chi-Square **RIGHT**; (n - 1) (s^2) / (X2 **RIGHT**) is the **RIGHT** end of the confidence interval.

Then there would be only one set of formulae, and each rule only involves one side, either left or right.

Throughout this whole discussion, there’s something funny going on with left and right. Although the normal curve table is “cumulative” (meaning that the area shown is to the left to infinity), the Chi Squared table shows area to the right without comment. Each discussion in this section mentions right before left. What am I not getting here?

Answer (score 1):

The author is, perhaps unfortunately, using "left" and "right" in two different contexts.  For the notation $\chi_R^2$ and $\chi_L^2$, the context is with respect to *critical values* of the chi-square distribution for which some underlying hypothesis is rejected.  These turn out to be quantiles of the distribution corresponding to some tail probability of observing an outcome greater than (in the case of $\chi_R^2$) or less than (in the case of $\chi_L^2$) that value.

However, for the confidence interval calculation, now "right" and "left" refer to the boundaries of the interval estimate.  As you observed, because of the way the interval is calculated, the "left" endpoint of the interval is calculated from the "right" critical value, and vice versa.

Because of this potential for confusion, I would prefer to avoid the use of such terminology entirely.  Instead, the critical values should just be referred to by their corresponding quantiles; e.g., $\chi_{\nu,\alpha}^2$ satisfies $$\Pr[X \le \chi_{\nu,\alpha}^2] = \alpha$$ for $X \sim \operatorname{ChiSquared}(\nu)$, and somewhat less common is the notation $\chi_{\nu,\alpha}^{2*} = \chi_{\nu,1-\alpha}^2$ for the upper $\alpha$ quantile satisfying $\Pr[X > \chi_{\nu,\alpha}^{2*}] = \alpha$.  For the referencing of the confidence limits, I usually call them the lower and upper confidence limits, rather than "left" and "right."